# Copying contents of one column into another column on a timer in Smartsheets

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is there a way that I can create a script where every Thursday at 4pm the contents of Column A is copied into Column C?

Any help would be appreciated.  Extremely novice coder/script writer here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Please see the Getting Started docs here: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/getting-started

This references a basic scenario with a sample implementation in several languages. The samples demonstrate how to load a sheet, loop through each row, read cell values. and update cell values. 
You will need to use system tools or additional code to schedule daily execution.

If you aren't a developer, you should consider automation solutions such as: https://azuqua.com/, https://zapier.com/, or https://flow.microsoft.com/